# create xml from tree like structure recursively

Tags: groovy

I've got tree-like structure

```
class FSNode {
    FSEntity data
    def parent
    def children = []

    boolean isRoot() {
        parent == null
    }
}
```

I instantiate it like this

```
// create filesystem folder
def fsEntityDirectory = new FSEntity(name: 'folder')
def fsDirectoryNode = new FSNode(parent: null, data: fsEntityDirectory)

def fsEntityDirectory2 = new FSEntity(name: 'folder1')
def fsDirectoryNode2 = new FSNode(parent: fsDirectoryNode, data: fsEntityDirectory2)

// create filesystem file
def fsEntity = new FSEntity(name: 'basic.txt', size: 10) // file system entity
def fsEntityNode = new FSNode(data: fsEntity, parent: fsDirectoryNode)

def fsEntity2 = new FSEntity(name: 'file.png', size: 12)
def fsEntityNode2 = new FSNode(data: fsEntity2, parent: fsDirectoryNode2)
fsDirectoryNode2.children << fsEntityNode2

fsDirectoryNode.children << fsDirectoryNode2
fsDirectoryNode.children << fsEntityNode
```

In the end I want to get something like this

```
<filesystem-root>
    <directory name="folder">
        <directory name="folder1">
            <file name="file.png" size="12" />
        </directory>
        <file name="basic.txt" size="10" />
    </directory>
</filesystem-root>
```

This is how I serialize

```
static def serializeFS(node, output, xml = new MarkupBuilder(output)) {
    if (node.children) {
        xml.directory(name: node.data.name)
        node.children.each {
            xml = serializeFS(it, output, xml)
        }
    } else {
        node.data.size ?
                xml.file(name: node.data.name, size: node.data.size) :
                xml.directory(name: node.data.name, "")
    }

    xml
}

static def wrapFS(output, xml) {
    xml."filesystem-root"(output)
}
```

But in the end I get

```
<directory name='folder' />
<directory name='folder1' />
<file name='file.png' size='12' />
<file name='basic.txt' size='10' />
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
def serializeFSNode(FSNode node, MarkupBuilder m) {
    if(node.children) {
        m.directory(name: node.data.name) {
            node.children.each { child ->
                serializeFSNode(child, m)
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        m."${node.data.size ? 'file' : 'directory'}"(name: node.data.name, size: node.data.size)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did not think about curly braces. Thanks!